# How to make cross site loading of form

Tags: javascript, forms, vue.js, embed, xss

I have problem that I don't quite know the right ters, so please bear with me

I have an idea to host vuejs+php form on my server.
I would like to make this form available to other websites with inserting like google and facebook are using, one div tag + js script from my server. NOT IFRAME!

Is it possible to make the form post data to the main web-server where it's embedded ?
Is it possible to make the form post data to my server where the js-file is coming from ?
I know that XSS will make this difficult either way...or impossible but are there something else to consider ?

Third matter that worries me is that what if customer's website already have vue and different version, can and should i wrap my vue into some encapsulation and is it even possible?

Thank you for understanding. I'm in really deep waters here...

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use iframe, may be web components would fit your case. Wrap your form in web component and create a new instance of the form on target site. 
Something like [this](https://vuejsdevelopers.com/2018/05/21/vue-js-web-component/)